# Storing contents of a text file in a dictonary

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to store a bunch of letters and corresponding values for them in a text file and then have the code go through and store all that in a dictionary

for example
the text file 
A = #
B = %

The dictionary will contain

```
Dict = {'A':'#', 'B':'%'}
```

how would I go about doing this in python and what should the text file look like?

Please note that each bit of information and its corresponding value will be on a new line

So far i have

```
d = {}
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[key] = val
print(d)
```

but it does not seem to work

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Show your effort thus far.

Comment: oh sorry my bad will edit right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# to read/load data from the file:
d = {}
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b = line.split('=')
        d[a.strip()] = b.strip()
```

To write to the file format output string for each line and then use either `write` or `writelines` method. Do a search and you will find plenty of information. You will need to iterate over dictionary's items like this:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    s = "{} = {}".format(k,v)
    # write s to file...
```